# Multiple maven repositories in one gradle file

Tags: maven, gradle, multiple-repositories

So my problem is how to add multiple maven repositories to one gradle file.

**This DOESN’T work:**

```
repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "http://maven.springframework.org/release"
        url "http://maven.restlet.org"
    }
}
```

**In short, you have to do like this.**

```
repositories {
  maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
  maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
}
```

Answer (score 653, accepted):

As mentioned in [gradleproject blog](https://gradleproject.wordpress.com/2013/02/14/multiple-maven-repositories-in-gradle/):

> You need to specify each maven URL in its own curly braces. Here is
> what I got working with skeleton dependencies for the web services
> project I’m going to build up:
>
> ```
> apply plugin: 'java'
>
> sourceCompatibility = 1.7
> version = '1.0'
>
> repositories {
>   maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
>   maven { url "http://maven.restlet.org" }
>   mavenCentral()
> }
>
> dependencies {
>   compile group:'org.restlet.jee', name:'org.restlet', version:'2.1.1'
>   compile group:'org.restlet.jee', name:'org.restlet.ext.servlet',version.1.1'
>   compile group:'org.springframework', name:'spring-web', version:'3.2.1.RELEASE'
>   compile group:'org.slf4j', name:'slf4j-api', version:'1.7.2'
>   compile group:'ch.qos.logback', name:'logback-core', version:'1.0.9'
>   testCompile group:'junit', name:'junit', version:'4.11'
> }
> ```

Comment: Is that the case regardless how closely related the URLs are?

Comment: Should we not expect `artifactUrls` to work? https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html#org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository:artifactUrls(java.lang.Object[])

Comment: Can I use it in init.gradle?

Comment: If i have sub-projects too, in that case, do i need to repositories with multiple url in configure(subprojects.findAll() ) {**} section too ?

Answer (score 100):

you have to do like this in your project level **gradle** file

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "http://dl.appnext.com/" }
        maven { url "https://maven.google.com" }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can I use it in init.gradle?