# Firebase notifications service is causing the app to crash

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have implemented Firebase notifications and it used to work just fine but now when I try to send a notification the app crash with `your app unexpectedly stopped working`

This is the log I got from google play console (my code seems fine)

```
java.lang.AbstractMethodError: 
  at com.google.firebase.iid.zzb$1.run (Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
  at java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:818)
```

**My dependencies**

```
dependencies {
compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
compile 'com.github.javiersantos:AppUpdater:2.6.3' 
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:design:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:24.2.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:10.2.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:10.0.1'
compile 'com.simplecityapps:recyclerview-fastscroll:1.0.11'
compile 'com.nshmura:snappysmoothscroller:1.0.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:10.0.1'
compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.4'
compile 'com.github.loregr:lgsnackbar:1.0.2'
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

**Screenshot of the error after changing to 11.4.0**
[image]

Comment: Please post your app-level gradle files. Might be a case of different dependency vesrions

Comment: @NovoLucas done

Comment: Try upgrading the version to 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'

Comment: I get this error when I try to build `Error:(35, 13) Failed to resolve: com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0`

Comment: Upgrade your play services to the same version as well. Meanwhile also post project level gradle

Answer (score 0):

Add Google Maven to your project level build.gradle file like this:

```
....
allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url "https://maven.google.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Change your dependencies to this:

```
ompile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:11.4.0'
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:11.4.0'
```

The list of all the latest version dependencies is [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup)

Comment: it asks me to update a repository, but I can't find it

Comment: Share the Screenshot if you can.

Comment: Done, check updatded question

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37310188/failed-to-resolve-com-google-firebasefirebase-core9-0-0/37310513

Comment: The problem is I must include `url "https://maven.google.com"` in the maven but the thing is the maven cannot accept more than one url and I already have one url

Comment: It doesn't matter how many URLs you have. Add them like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114860/multiple-maven-repositories-in-one-gradle-file