# How to rename a maven repository in Gradle

Tags: gradle, groovy

If I add 2 repositories in my build.gradle file, they will be autonamed ("maven" and "maven2") :

```
repositories {
  maven { url "http://maven.springframework.org/release" }
  maven { url "https://maven.fabric.io/public" }
}
```

Is there a way to name them explicitely ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You [should just be able to use](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.artifacts.repositories.MavenArtifactRepository.html) `name`

```
repositories {
  maven {
      url "http://maven.springframework.org/release"
      name 'spring-repo'
  }
  maven {
      url "https://maven.fabric.io/public"
      name 'fabric-repo'
  }
}
```

Comment: Ok, thanks ! I was missing the "new line" separator, not familiar with groovy yet, if u put a ',' or a ';' or even some ':' between attribute and value, it just doesn't work.

Comment: `;` should work, but you may need to put the braces back in, ie: `url('http...'); name('woo')`

Comment: BTW, you should use https for all repos, as http is being deprecated

Comment: ok, thx for the syntax tips ! These repos are just a copy/paste from a popular answer, I'm not using them. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30114860/multiple-maven-repositories-in-one-gradle-file

Comment: @Tristan just checking Have fun!